# Show the system menu on demand, within a QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Usually, right-click on the title-bar of a window make a `system-menu` to popup.

[image]

My question is: How to force this menu to popup on demand: like for example while clicking on a button.

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QWidget window;
window.resize(200,100);
QPushButton button(&window);
button.connect( &button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&window]()
{
    // here show the window system menu:
    // window.showSystemMenu(QPoint(0,0));
});
window.show();

a.exec();
```

Note: to use this signal/slot with lambda, it is required C++11. But a pure C++03 is also valid.

EDIT:

I actually create this menu as a QMenu, which I populate with same content than the default Windows menu. That would work in any platform but the content could be different than the expected.

Comment: I am still looking for an answer which do not make use of per-platform libraries. Said in another way, using QT as indicated in the TAG.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is Windows specific menu, you have to use Windows native API to get and show the system menu. Assuming that you implemented a slot and connect it to your button's `clicked()` signal:

```
void MyClass::onButtonClicked()
{
#ifdef WIN32
    HMENU systemMenu = ::GetSystemMenu(window.winId(), FALSE);
    if (systemMenu) {
        // Open system menu in the left top corner of window.
        TrackPopupMenu(systemMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN|TPM_LEFTBUTTON,
                       window.pos().x(), window.pos().y(), NULL,
                       w.winId(), 0);
    }

#endif
}
```

where `window` is a `QWidget`.

Comment: Thanks you! I will maybe go to something like that as a last option. But we use QT to make the application cross-platform, an this feature is available on most window managers.

Comment: Note: `window` is `yourWidget->window();`